# Protect override built-in js objects

Tags: javascript, security

Is the way to protect overriding native Date object? Or detect that execution environment was changed?

For example, someone hack my code and override Date like this:

```
function Date() {
    this.getMonth = function() {
        return 13;
    };
}
```

Thank in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "*someone hack my code*"? If someone can make arbitrary changes to your code, they can also remove any "protection" you add.

Comment: @melpomene for example, i added to the page third-party script ( potentially it can add others)

Comment: @NataZakharchuk: If you can't trust the script, don't add it to the page.

Comment: You can't trust anything, not even your own database.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could do some things to protect built-ins; but **no**, you can't prevent hacking by the user in control of the browser. They can do just about anything they want. Adding any code to protect the builtins doesn't prevent them using code before yours runs to defeat your attempts to protect the built-ins.

Since the user can only affect themselves in this way, don't worry about it.

Just remember the cardinal rule: You can't trust anything the client sends you. Validate everything server-side. The "client" may not even be a web browser; someone could be sending you custom-crafted HTTP messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop another script from overriding a global object at the client side.

But if you are suspecting that a third party script might be doing so, you could create a local reference of `Date` and use it instead:

```
var mySuperSecretObject = Date;
var today = new mySuperSecretObject();
var month = today.getMonth();
```

Of course, if the third party script executes **before** your JS runs, your script might not get the correct `Date` object to begin with, and your new object (`mySuperSecretObject`) will not work as expected either. There isn't much you can do in such case.